# Making MUI_PAGE_DIRECTORY page field readonly?

Tags: nsis

Is it possible to make the the destination folder field in MUI_PAGE_DIRECTORY page readonly and disable the browse button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
InstallDir "$ProgramFiles\Whatever"

!include MUI2.nsh
!include WinMessages.nsh
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_WELCOME
!define MUI_PAGE_CUSTOMFUNCTION_SHOW RestrictDirPage
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_DIRECTORY
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_INSTFILES
!insertmacro MUI_LANGUAGE English

Function RestrictDirPage
!if "${MUI_SYSVERSION}" >= 2.0
SendMessage $mui.DirectoryPage.Directory ${EM_SETREADONLY} 1 0
EnableWindow $mui.DirectoryPage.BrowseButton 0
!else
FindWindow $0 '#32770' '' $HWNDPARENT
GetDlgItem $1 $0 0x3FB
SendMessage $1 ${EM_SETREADONLY} 1 0
GetDlgItem $1 $0 0x3E9
EnableWindow $1 0
!endif
FunctionEnd
```

Comment: Thank you @Anders!